# How to use one Mobile App connection in Xamarin across all applications

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

I'm currently creating my first application using Xamarin PCL(without Xamarin.Forms) and Azure Mobile App. What would be the best approach to use only one instance of `MobileServiceClient` across all applications? If it's not possible to use it from PCL, then is there any way to do it the same way, but only across iOS app?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to code sharing when you say *instance*, the [Azure Mobile Apps Client SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/) enables you to do that. You can consume the SDK from your PCL and use your PCL from your platform targets/projects.

Comment: I'm going to use authentication in my app and as far as I'm concerned Azure SDK can automatically store user credentials in app, so user won't have to relogin. Will this feature work if I'll consume Mobile App SDK from PCL? And the thing I wanted is similar to what I've done in Windows Phone(native development): in App.xaml.cs I've created(i.e.) `MyVariable` and then from any place in code I could use it with `(App.Current as App).MyVariable`. So maybe something like this is possible in Xamarin PCL and Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: To clarify, the auth token is *not* automatically persisted by the SDK, but there is guidance in the docs should you wish to do that. 
The approach you're describing would definitely work with the PCL.

Comment: Can you please share link to this guidance? I'm currently following this one https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-ios-get-started-users/, but it doesn't look like it has information about saving auth token.